# Concatenating/Merging 2 DataSets with exact same columns

Tags: reporting-services, merge, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to figure out if there is any way in Report Builder 3.0 to concatenate or merge 2 different "DataSet" objects which both have exactly the same column names into one set of data, for the purposes of displaying in a pie chart.

My SQL query looks similar to this for both data sets:

```sql
DECLARE @DateCreatedStart date = GETDATE()-14
DECLARE @DateCreatedEnd date = GETDATE()

SELECT i.Source, COUNT(*) AS Count_of_Source
FROM [DBName].[dbo].[Items] i
WHERE (i.DateCreated BETWEEN @DateCreatedStart AND @DateCreatedEnd)
GROUP BY i.Source
```

So I end up with 2 data sets which both have `Source` and `Count_of_Source` columns.

Edit: I've found out that I can't use the Lookup function how I thought I might be able to. It just looks in one dataset and finds a match in another dataset, and pulls a value from the same row in a similar manner to Excel's vlookup/hlookup.

Edit more info: I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24312870/1804496 that showed me I could use a scope parameter on my expression to specify the name of my second data set. I added a second values member that uses an expression `=SUM(Fields!Count_of_Source.Value, "DataSet2")`, but the chart looks completely wrong and I don't know how to fix it at the moment. It looks like the single row from my second data set is being repeated `n` times, where `n` is equal to the number of unique `Source` values from my first data set. No idea what is going on there.

Comment: The short answer is no. (There is no long answer.)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to combine the datasets is using the SQL Server. So you can just add a new dataset and paste in the two queries with a `UNION ALL` between them.